# intToBin with large numbers

Tags: r

I'm using the intToBin() function from "R.utils" package and am having trouble using it to convert large decimal numbers to binary.

I get this error : NAs introduced by coercion.

Is there another function out there that can handle big numbers/ is there an algorithm/ code to implement such a function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you read the help page for `intToBin`, it quite explicitly says it takes "integer" inputs.  These are not mathematical "integers" but rather the computer-language-defined ints, which are limited to 16 bits (or something like that).

You'll need to find (or write :-() a function which converts floating-point numbers to binary floats, or if you're lucky, perhaps `Rmpfr` or `gmp` packages, which do arbitrary precision "big number" math, may have a float-to-binary tool.

By the time this gets posted, someone will have exposed my ignorance by posting an existing function, w/ my luck.

Edit -- like maybe the package `pack`

Comment: As the author of [pack](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pack/), I'd be grateful for any patches and/or enhancements.  I wrote that package to use in another package... and the other package is now obsolete, but I still thought pack may be useful to others.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich See my answer, you can use it in your package if you deem it relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a converter between doubles and hex numbers. So I wrote those, might be helpful to others

```
doubleToHex <- function(x) {
  if(x < 16)
    return(sprintf("%X", x))

  remainders <- c()
  while(x > 15) {
    remainders <- append(remainders, x%%16)
    x <- floor(x/16)
  }
  remainders <- paste(sprintf("%X", rev(remainders)), collapse="")
  return(paste(x, remainders, sep=""))
}

hexToDouble <- function(x) {
  x <- strsplit(x,"")[[1]]
  output <- as.double(0)
  for(i in rev(seq_along(x))) {
    output <- output + (as.numeric(as.hexmode(x[i]) * (16**(length(x)-i))))
  }
  return(output)
}

doubleToHex(x = 8356723)
hexToDouble(x = "7F8373")
```

Hasn't been extensively tested yet, let me know if you detect a problem with it.